# Understanding theMap.on('click') event of Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I inherited code from another person and some of the lines are as follows:

```
       theMap.on('click', function(e) {
        minx = (e.latlng.lng - 0.0000001).toFixed(7);
        miny = (e.latlng.lat - 0.0000001).toFixed(7);
        maxx = e.latlng.lng.toFixed(7);
        maxy = e.latlng.lat.toFixed(7);
```

Does this mean that these display the coordinates of the map on a single click?

Comment: I just rolled this back so as not to invalidate an existing answer which was offered in good faith.  If you have a new question then ask that in a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

When the user clicks on the map, this event is fired.

the parameter `e` contains the clicked location.

Your code computes a new coordinate  0.0000001 degrees away from the click coordinate and save the new coordinates in a variable. It does nothing with it (at least not in the the code you have published)

MAYBE the intent is to build a square box, having the top right corner at the clicked coordinates.

Comment: Another potential to try would be to print console.log statements for your variables to see what is going on in your map

Comment: i solved it. yes i think the intent is to build a box around the clicked location to return values of feature classes.